# Can I add a library refence to existing Shared Object?

Tags: shared-libraries, unix, elf, dynamic-linking

I have a system "fsimage.so" that requires mkdirp, which just happens to live in libgen.so. But fsimage.so does not know this. For example:

```
# ldd /usr/lib/python2.4/vendor-packages/fsimage.so
    libfsimage.so.1.0 =>     /usr/lib/libfsimage.so.1.0
    libxml2.so.2 =>  /lib/libxml2.so.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/sfw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
    libz.so.1 =>     /lib/libz.so.1
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
    libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
    libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
    libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1

# ./test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test", line 26, in ?
    import fsimage
ImportError: ld.so.1: isapython2.4: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/lib/python2.4/vendor-packages/fsimage.so: symbol mkdirp: referenced symbol not found

# LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libgen.so ./test
Usage: ./test
```

Naturally, if I had the sources etc, I could simply link it again, and add "-lgen", and it will add libgen.so as a dependency.

But as an exercise in hackery, say I do not have any sources, and simply wanted to add that fsimage.so needs to also load libgen.so. Using elfedit/objcopy etc, is this not possible? I don't suppose I can use "ld" to use .so as input, and write a new .so with extra library?

```
# elfdump /usr/lib/python2.4/vendor-packages/fsimage.so|grep NEEDED
   [0]  NEEDED            0x5187              libfsimage.so.1.0
   [1]  NEEDED            0x5152              libxml2.so.2
   [2]  NEEDED            0x5171              libgcc_s.so.1
```

First attempt at stackoverflow, go easy on me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you "Employed Russian", you gave me the information needed to search deeper. Solaris already ships with "elfedit", so if others wants to know, these are the instructions

```
# elfedit libfsimage.so.1.0.0 libfsimage.so.1.0.0-new
> dyn:value DT_NEEDED
 index  tag                value
   [0]  NEEDED            0x4f81              libpthread.so.1
   [1]  NEEDED            0x4fac              libxml2.so.2
   [2]  NEEDED            0x4fc2              libgcc_s.so.1
> dyn:value -add -s DT_NEEDED libscf.so
 index  tag                value
  [35]  NEEDED            0x500d              libscf.so
> dyn:value DT_NEEDED
 index  tag                value
   [0]  NEEDED            0x4f81              libpthread.so.1
   [1]  NEEDED            0x4fac              libxml2.so.2
   [2]  NEEDED            0x4fc2              libgcc_s.so.1
  [35]  NEEDED            0x500d              libscf.so
> :write
> :quit

# ldd libfsimage.so.1.0.0-new
    libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
    libxml2.so.2 =>  /lib/libxml2.so.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/sfw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    libscf.so =>     /lib/libscf.so
    libz.so.1 =>     /lib/libz.so.1
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
    libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
    libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
    libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
    libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
    libnvpair.so.1 =>        /lib/libnvpair.so.1
    libsmbios.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libsmbios.so.1
    libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
```

Comment: I run elfedit with the so I want to edit as first arg and a newname for the second and nothing happens. The help is shown. I'm on Linux though.

Answer (score 7):

Not easily.

Most `UNIX` systems (`AIX` is a notable exception) consider `*.so` a "final" link product, and it is not suitable as an input for any further link.

To add a new DT_NEEDED tag to the dynamic section of `fsimage.so`, you would need to rewrite its `.dynamic` section. Removing an entry from `.dynamic` is relatively easy -- you can just "slide" the other entries up, and replace the last entry with `DT_NULL`.

On the other hand, adding a new entry requires that you append a whole new `.dynamic` section to the file, and then update all pointers (offsets) within `fsimage.so` to point to the new section. This requires "deep" understanding of the ELF format.

There are existing tools to do this, e.g. [`rpath`](http://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/changing_elf_runpaths) but I've had mixed success with it.

Comment: I suspected as such. I know Solaris will leave 512 bytes of space in ELF, so you can easily add new sections, like text etc. But not (directly/easily) expanding DT_NEEDED sections. Still interesting learning. For now, I could recompile my python and add the libraries I wanted, but entered a separate mess of 32bit vs 64bit. Sigh :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PatchELF](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html). Release 0.9 is out since 29 Feb 2016 and lets you:

- Change the dynamic loader ("ELF interpreter") of executables
- Change the RPATH of executables and libraries
- Shrink the RPATH of executables and libraries
- Remove declared dependencies on dynamic libraries (DT_NEEDED
  entries)
- **Add a declared dependency on a dynamic library (DT_NEEDED)**
- Replace a declared dependency on a dynamic library with another one (DT_NEEDED)
- Change SONAME of a dynamic library

In your case:

```
$ patchelf --add-needed /usr/lib/libgen.so /usr/lib/python2.4/vendor-packages/fsimage.so
```

Comment: The most recent stable release [v0.8][1]  has only `--remove-needed LIBRARY` and not add, probably for the reason stated by lundman in the accepted version. However the [development version in github][2] does have the --add-library option as well, so this could be the way to go [1]:https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/blob/0.8/src/patchelf.cc [2]:https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/blob/master/src/patchelf.cc